# DNS on static IP address

Tags: dns, ip-address

I have setup my mythtv server (runnning ubuntu 12.04) to have a static IP address.

This is required because the IPAddress must be hardcoded in the mythtv server settings and if it changes the the mythtv client will not be able to connect.

I did this using the UI (command line answers will not be accepted) using:
Network Connections -> Wired -> Edit -> IPv4

and setting the settings as follows:

[image]

This works great for mythtv however I can no longer access the internet via domain names. if I use the IPaddress it works but I can't resolve the DNS entries.

If I look at Connection Information UI it does not list any Primary DNS: (entry is not there at all) like it is when on DHCP.

[image]

How do I configure my DNS with a static IPAddress using the GUI?

Comment: You are entering the settings correctly. Are you sure `192.168.1.1` is your DNS server? What happens if you enter `8.8.8.8`? And what is the output of `host www.google.com` run in a terminal when using the regular DNS server?

Comment: I'm sure 192.168.1.1 is my DNS server because my other computers which are using DHCP have this listed as there primary DNS in Connection Information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a final resort I disabled and then enabled my networking. This solved the problem. It appears that the connection manager can't apply the connection settings until the connection is restarted.

The user interface gives no indication that the settings are not yet applied. Which is really quite poor.

Comment: This really is a bug then. I mean, I have never had any issues, while I'm using this quite often (got several Wired Connection configurations in all sorts).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to do it via the gui, but if you type:

```
echo nameserver 192.168.1.1 >> /etc/resolv.conf
```

as 'root' that should work for you (if you aren't root, you'll need to through a `sudo` in front of that).